# Sections indexed with numbers, subsections with letters

Tags: sectioning, numbering

Is it possible to set the environment in such a way that sections are indexed with numbers, and subsections with letters?

I mean, I'd like to have the following result:

### 1 First section

**1.a First subsection**

**1.b Second subsection**

...

### 2 Second section

**2.a First subsection**

**2.b Second subsection**

...

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Redefine `\thesubsection` as `\thesection.\alph{subsection}`. (`\alph` replaces the default `\arabic`; you could also choose, e.g., `\Alph`, `\roman`, and `\Roman`.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\alph{subsection}}

\begin{document}

\section{First}

\subsection{First-first}

\section{Second}

\end{document}
```

[image]